# Is EventPhases.Initiated and EventPhases.TransactionCommitted in Event System always triggers from same Tridion server

Tags: 2013-sp1

I have two Tridion CMS servers for load balancing and I'm developing an Event Handler where two separate methods are triggered on EventPhases.Initiated and EventPhases.TransactionCommitted for same event.
Can someone please confirm if both the methods will always be triggered from same server or can be triggered from two separate Tridion servers? I store some value in ContextVariables in initiated phase and use it in TransactionCommitted phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think I can say with enough authority for *ALL* events, but definitely CRUD events are started and finished within the same instance. I am inclined to say that yes, all are running in a single instance, but there may be some less used event that for some reason would be distributed (can't think of any).

Comment: In general, the TOM.NET event system is in-process meaning that all events are triggered in the same process/machine where the triggering action is executed.  Synchronous event handlers  even run on the same thread, but async event handlers and event handlers for TransactionCompleted/Aborted events run on a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks Rick and Nuno for sharing your knowledge on this. I'm using synchronous event handlers which run on the same thread. This fulfill my acceptance criteria.